# Retrieving job result attributes in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, ibm-q-experience, qaoa, ibm-quantum-devices

I am trying to optimize a Hamiltonian using QAOA in IBM Qiskit.

I used the following 'minimize' function to get my result. (I am not including the whole code because it will get unnecessarily long).

```
   res = minimize(cost_func, x0, args=(ansatz, hamiltonian, estimator), method="COBYLA")
   res
```

When I ran the problem on a 'ibmq qasm simulator' I got the following result:

```
fun: -23.1424
   maxcv: 0.0
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 45
  status: 1
 success: True
       x: array([3.39824022, 4.17447906, 2.86297948, 3.1139919 ])
```

As you can see, I got multiple attributes in the solution.

But when I ran this on an actual quantum computer (ibm brisbane), I used the same code and same variable 'res'; it went on Queue and I had to wait for around 4-5 hours. But after the job was done, I cannot get the value for res which was defined in the previous line of code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Cell In[1], line 1
    res
NameError: name 'res' is not defined
```

And I tried using job.result() but that doesn't have the required attributes I got from the results of the simulator stored in variable 'res'.

How can I get the attributes such as res.x from the already completed job? It is very much needed for my further work.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our community! Thanks for your contribution and we hope to see much more of you in the future!

Comment: can you add the versions for `qiskit` and `qiskit-ibm-provider`/`qiskit_ibm_runtime` you are using?

Comment: I am using the versions: qiskit 0.44.1, qiskit_ibm_runtime 0.11.3, and qiskit_ibm_provider 0.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

If the job was completed, you should be able to see the result on [IBM Quantum Platform](https://quantum.ibm.com/jobs). If you would like to retrieve the result within the `ipython` notebook, something like this should work :

```
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService

# Initialize the account first.
service = QiskitRuntimeService()

jobs =service.jobs(backend_name="ibm_brisbane")
```

This will return all jobs you've run on `ibm_brisbane`.

Please see [monitor a job](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/run/monitor-job) for more info.